# Constructing explicit lift of a circle homeomorphism

Tags: limits, algebraic-topology, continuity, dynamical-systems, covering-spaces

Studying a book by Luis Barreira in the Universitext Collection -- Dynamical Systems: an Introduction -- I'm told that given $f: S^{1} \to S^{1}$ homeomorphism, it's always possible to construct a lift $F(x) = f(x - \lfloor x \rfloor ) + \lfloor x \rfloor$, where $f(x - \lfloor x \rfloor)$ is taken to be the representative in $[0,1[$. It's easy for me to check that this is indeed a lift, but I can't ensure myself about continuity. It's obviously continuous in $\mathbb{R} \setminus \mathbb{Z}$, so it's left to check that left and right limits coincide in $\mathbb{Z}$. First, $F(k) = f(0) + k$, and $F(k^{+}) = f(0) + k$ as well. Now the author claims that $F(k^{-}) = f(1) + k$, and since $f(1) = f(0)$ we'd be done. I can't, however, verify this assertion: I always conclude that $F(k^{-}) = f(1) + k -1$. Where does the $-1$ goes in his calculations?

Comment: I don't think this construction for $F$ makes any sense. Consider the rotation $f(x) = (x + 0.5) \mod 1$. Under this definition, the values of $F$ for $(0, 0.25, 0.5, 0.75,1)$ are $(0.5, 0.75, 0, 0.25, 1.5)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The limit of $f(x)$ as $x\rightarrow 1$ is NOT $f(0)$ but $f(0) +1,$ which cancels the other one.

Comment: I'm sorry, can you work that out a little bit? I can't see where the $+1$ comes from!

Comment: I mean, $f$ is a circle homeomorphism, so everything is $\pmod 1$ right?

Comment: An example of a circle homeo is $x \rightarrow x$ Clearer now?

Comment: @ulilaka The values of $f$ are understood $\mod 1$ when we consider it as a map from circle to circle. But in the formula $F(x) = f(x - \lfloor x \rfloor ) + \lfloor x \rfloor$  we build a map from $\mathbb R$ to $\mathbb R$. The values of $f$ are understood as real numbers here. This is why taking the limit $x\to 1^-$ in this formula yields $f(0)+1$, not $f(0)$.

Comment: @IgorRivin Would you mind inspecting my answer to this question? I believe his function is not continuous, right?

Answer (score 1):

I think the function $F(x) = f(x - \lfloor x \rfloor ) + \lfloor x \rfloor$ is not a continuous lift.

Let $S_1$ be $[0, 1]$ with $0, 1$ identified and let $f$ be rotation by $\frac 14$, $f(x) = x + \frac 14 \pmod 1.$  Let $F(x)$ be defined as above. Then

$$\lim_{x \to \frac 34^-}F(x) = 1$$
while
$$\lim_{x \to \frac 34^+}F(x) = 0.$$

Comment: I think it is just a matter of understanding what the formula implicitly says, as it was the case in my question: as $x \to 3/4^+$, $x - \lfloor x \rfloor \to 3/4^+$. But $f$ is assumed to be a homeomorphism of the circle, so $f(3/4^+)$ must be $f(3/4)$. But in the circle $0$ is $1$, so there's no particular reason to plug in $0$ instead of $1$, it is ill-defined a priori because we are mixing different worlds without a clear dictionary between them. These are just clumsy instruction to glue the pieces of the graph of $f$ inside the square on top of each other and repeat indefinitely.

Comment: @ulilaka Yeah I agree that these sorts of functions are very clumsy, while the idea is clear. I will have to check this again later, but I'm still not very happy with this function. $F$ is supposed to take values in $\mathbb{R}$, where $0$ is not $1$.